# Document OnLoad isn't working

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a main function in JS and I want to call it when the document loads, but not as an attribute of body.
My code is the following:

```
var program = {
    main: function(args) {
        alert(args)
    }
}

document.onload = function() {
    program.main("xyz")
}
```

But I really don't understand why in the world it doesn't work.
Can you guys give me some help to do it work?

And in my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./libs/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us more code? Where exactly did you place this script?

Comment: Use `window.onload` http://jsfiddle.net/K6S8k/ Here is the original code with document http://jsfiddle.net/K6S8k/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Huangism is right about attaching the on load to the window not the document. I use this combination for most of my page set ups, allows you to start async file loads etc earlier than on load and then change DOM content after on load.

```
(function preLoad(){  /*runs before content is loaded, rest of content won't load until this has completed*/

window.addEventListener('load', function(){onLoad();}, false);
}());

function onLoad(){  /*runs after content is loaded and page has loaded*/


};
```

Also neatly packages your set up functions, easy to maintain and read! :)